# Meshes are semi-transparent

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I was on wireframe view using the knife tool on a mesh and when I finished and went out of it I realized everything was semi-transparent and I don't know why. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I want to know how I can turn everything back to normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle "X-Ray Mode" in the upper right-hand corner.

[image: X-Ray Button location]